# Angular 2 block ui component

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the proper way to block the ui of a component in Angular 2?

Something like this

```
<component [blockUI]="true"></component>
```

Comment: what should "block ui" accomplish? lock down the entire page? disable certain items?

Comment: disable user interaction with the component, no click, keyboard, selection, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the component's less file put:

```
:host {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you have components below, they will get the clicks, if you'd like to prevent this, instead of the css do:

```
<component (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
```

to make it dynamic, assuming you use less and have a variable called `notInteractive`:

```
:host {
  &.not-interactive {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried out the first option since I don't have nested components and it worked well, now how would I set it back to enable it? I need it to be dynamic as to whether it is disabled or not